# Android - How to parse Gmail HTML messages to plain text?

Tags: android, html, parsing, plaintext, gmail-api

I'm fetching GMail messages from new GMail API. I finally achieve to get Body Content from emails and most of them has complex html.

I tried to use [Snacktory](https://github.com/karussell/snacktory) library but the results are not so good (parsing webs works pretty well).

Did you know alternatives that works better with "email html" or a way to ask gmail for a text/plain format perhaps?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the Gmail API to work with android? I am trying to get it up and running and always get a 403 response from the server. Needless to day the API is turned on on the API console and I have created a new Client oauth key. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this: [Android Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

For most cases this has been enough for me.

Hope this helps.

Best Regards.